# Combining Bing Custom Search and Bing Video?

Tags: bing-api

Bing Video API supports integrating Bing Video to your website.
Bing Custom Search lets you choose from which websites, you want to get results.

How can I make it so that the integrated search engine on my page shows only video results from websites that I specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bing Custom Search doesn't support videos for now. However, if your list of websites is small, you can use the Bing Video Search API with **site:Your_site** operator. You can combine multiple sites using "OR" like this: **site:Your_site_1.com** OR **site:Your_site_2.com** OR ....